# copy value entered in unbound textbox to label after pressing button

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an unbound text box on my form which the admin can enter a date of when records were last updated. I want this date to be copied to a label after pushing a button so that it holds the date instead of it do disappear after closing the form.

does anyone know if this is possible and how it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

For creating a variable that can be used AFTER the form is closed:

1. Create a new module (in code window, click 'Insert | Module'
2. Insert the variable name(s) and types you want available everywhere. i.e.

   Global dtLastUpdated    As Date

   Global strSaveSomeName  As String
3. Save the module as mdl_Globals
4. Add code wherever needed to set the variable, then can reference anywhere.

If for use during the form, use the following: where 'lblForUnbound' is the Label field and 'txtUnbound' is your unbound text box

```
Me.lblForUnbound.Caption = Me.txtUnbound.Text
```

Comment: I'd like to save the value for after closing. I've never worked with variants before so I don't know where to handle them...?

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to create a global variable.